# Grammars - RegEx

Tags: regex

I am trying to construct a regular expression that the total number of a's is divisible by 3 no matter how they are distributed. aabaabbaba.  This is What i came up with:

```
b*ab*ab*
```

Now, someone told me i could do it this way

```
(b*ab*ab*)*
```

Why would i need to enclose it and why is the outside kleene star needed?

Wouldnt the outside kleene distribute among all the a's and b's inside the parenthesis? if thats the case then what would a double kleene mean?

Comment: Your expression is wrong. `aa` matches the regex and 2 is not divisible by 3

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa, spatulamania's answer is definitely correct, and yours is plain wrong. Here's a small Python demo that does not use any non-regular expression stuff like back-references or recursive patterns: http://ideone.com/ycZXb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the number of 'a's to be divisible by three, you'll need three 'a's in your expression.  So the correct expression is:

`(b*ab*ab*ab*)*`

This expression is saying 'a' three times, with possible 'b's in the middle.  The last star says repeat (the whole parenthesized expression) as necessary.

Comment: +1 But you need to add `^` and `$` anchors to make this work: `^(b*ab*ab*ab*)*$`

Comment: ridgerunner: anchors are irrelevant here, as the focus is obviously construction of a formal language, not application of a regex in programming. Note also that in theoretical CS regexes don't need more than alternatives, the Kleene star and grouping to represent all possible regular languages.

Comment: @Joey - Yes I am ignorant of the theoretical CS. But I must respectively insist that the regex: `(b*ab*ab*ab*)*` erroneously matches `"aaaa"` which certainly has a number of `a`s NOT divisible by three.

Comment: ridgerunner, in this context it doesn't. Regexes are tools for describing languages by enumerating all matching words of a language. The anchors are implied there as in theoretical CS regexes don't apply to substrings. They are not programming tools in that context.

Answer (score 0):

The outer `*` repeats the *entire sequence* zero or more times.

In other words, zero or more substrings that match `b*ab*ab*`.